# Empty json response using python-gcm

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, google-cloud-messaging

I always get an empty json response `{}` when I try to send a message through GCM.

I'm using [python-gcm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-gcm)  and this is my code:

```
from gcm import GCM

API_KEY = "AldaSyAwnh5jAAAAAAABvBTyqDdMITCoEE8GLZ"
my_gcm = GCM(api_key=API_KEY)
data = {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'}


# JSON request
#reg_ids = ['12', '34', '69']
reg_ids = ['ALA91bE9QSkVKcmAAAAAAda8UsNs27R-29pJHDqwIiwqxSAStmhpFo2hKD0SipoCjgANvFJ7trdQZuJCjMaUAAAA6zmETYDncD9YTiVZ61eG1pwXdOJC7mozlt76OoyM81OasWi9_ibGklNfhWGhJpg']
response = my_gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, data=data)

# Handling errors
if 'errors' in response:
    for error, reg_ids in response['errors'].items():
        # Check for errors and act accordingly
        if error is 'NotRegistered':
            # Remove reg_ids from database
            for reg_id in reg_ids:
                entity.filter(registration_id=reg_id).delete()

if 'canonical' in response:
    for reg_id, canonical_id in response['canonical'].items():
        # Repace reg_id with canonical_id in your database
        entry = entity.filter(registration_id=reg_id)
        entry.registration_id = canonical_id
        entry.save()
```

What i'm doing wrong, should I try another alternative?
Another details:

- I'm using flask.
- In my developer google console I have google maps

  activated too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is ofuscated, just for be sure I'm using the right values.

Comment: Good, but that wasn't clear from what you posted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like is not posible use python-gcm directly.
Then, according to:

- [Flask-gcm](https://github.com/MichiganLabs/flask-gcm)
- [Its docs](http://gcm-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#usage)
- [Its source code](https://bitbucket.org/sardarnl/gcm-client/src/c1ae4a4c9804b623456ffdd3a4531aa554816087/gcmclient/gcm.py)

And take in mind the flag `dry_run=True` is for testing.
The following code works like a charm :)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from flask.ext.gcm import GCM
API_KEY = "AldaSyAwnh5jAAAAAAABvBTyqDdMITCoEE8GLZ"
gcm = GCM()
app.config['GCM_KEY'] = API_KEY
gcm.init_app(app)

data = {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'}

multicast = JSONMessage(["ALA91bE9QSkVKcmAAAAAAda8UsNs27R-29pJHDqwIiwqxSAStmhpFo2hKD0SipoCjgANvFJ7trdQZuJCjMaUAAAA6zmETYDncD9YTiVZ61eG1pwXdOJC7mozlt76OoyM81OasWi9_ibGklNfhWGhJpg"], data, collapse_key='my.key', dry_run=False)

try:
    # attempt send
    res_multicast = gcm.send(multicast)

for res in [res_multicast]:
    # nothing to do on success
    for reg_id, msg_id in res.success.items():
        print "Successfully sent %s as %s" % (reg_id, msg_id)

    # update your registration ID's
    for reg_id, new_reg_id in res.canonical.items():
        print "Replacing %s with %s in database" % (reg_id, new_reg_id)

    # probably app was uninstalled
    for reg_id in res.not_registered:
        print "Removing %s from database" % reg_id

    # unrecoverably failed, these ID's will not be retried
    # consult GCM manual for all error codes
    for reg_id, err_code in res.failed.items():
        print "Removing %s because %s" % (reg_id, err_code)

    # if some registration ID's have recoverably failed
    if res.needs_retry():
        # construct new message with only failed regids
        retry_msg = res.retry()
        # you have to wait before attemting again. delay()
        # will tell you how long to wait depending on your
        # current retry counter, starting from 0.
        print "Wait or schedule task after %s seconds" % res.delay(retry)
        # retry += 1 and send retry_msg again

except GCMAuthenticationError:
    # stop and fix your settings
    print "Your Google API key is rejected"
except ValueError, e:
    # probably your extra options, such as time_to_live,
    # are invalid. Read error message for more info.
    print "Invalid message/option or invalid GCM response"
    print e.args[0]
except Exception:
    # your network is down or maybe proxy settings
    # are broken. when problem is resolved, you can
    # retry the whole message.
    print "Something wrong with requests library"
```

Comment: Hey man, I'm attempting to implement this now, everything seems to go through fine and I am getting successful responses back, but I am still not seeing push sent to be devices. Any idea? Everything seems to be set up fine, API key, code, etc.

Comment: @parchambeau Did you set dry_run=False ?